# python getting download from a website. the target machine actively refused it

Tags: python, python-requests, urllib

I don't know webscraping enough to figure this out. There is a website I want to get data from. I get an error of

> [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

So when you go to the url website it is supposed to download the data based on the url parameters.
I also want to specify the file path the file saves to.

I tried

```
import urllib.request
from datetime import date

today = date.today()
str_day = today.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

url = f"http://data.usbr.gov/rise/api/result/download?after=2020-05-28&before={str_day}&filename=Lake%20Mead%20Hoover%20Dam%20and%20Powerplant%20Daily%20Lake%2FReservoir%20Storage-af%20Time%20Series%20Data&itemId=6124&order=ASC&type=csv"

opener = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
file_out = open("download.csv", "wb")
file_out.write(opener.readall())
file_out.close()
```

I also tried.

```
import requests
from datetime import date

today = date.today()
str_day = today.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

url = f"http://data.usbr.gov/rise/api/result/download?after=2020-05-28&before={str_day}&filename=Lake%20Mead%20Hoover%20Dam%20and%20Powerplant%20Daily%20Lake%2FReservoir%20Storage-af%20Time%20Series%20Data&itemId=6124&order=ASC&type=csv"
r = requests.get(url)
```

Comment: What if you print `url` and then try pasting that into a browser?

Comment: The error means that when you sent a TCP connection request, the server responded with a RESET. This usually means that a service listening on a port number didn't like your IP address or simply won't take _any_ connection requests on that port. As mentioned above, a web site that only takes HTTPS requests may do this on its HTTP port.

Comment: @RandomDavis The url works, browser will start downloading the file.

Comment: Some browsers (Chrome, for me) will automatically change the URL to use HTTPS if HTTP fails, but in Python you have to use the correct one.  In Chrome, the padlock symbol next to the url indicates HTTPS is being used.

Comment: @ShaneS - Interesting. That could mean that it needs user agent and content types in the header.

Comment: @MarkTolonen - My  chrome downloaded with the non-secure url but my python failed. So, I'm thinking other header info is needed.

Comment: @tdelaney What I used in my answer worked for me, but I have seen websites that require more header info in the past.   I also pasted the non-secure url in Chrome, but chrome switched to HTTPS as indicated by the padlock.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The URL uses HTTPS.  The error means no process is listening on the port (the HTTP port 80).  You can also use a parameters dictionary to make the parameters more readable:

```py
import requests
from datetime import date

today = date.today()
str_day = today.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

url = 'https://data.usbr.gov/rise/api/result/download'

params = {'after': '2020-05-28',
          'before': str_day,
          'filename': 'Lake Mead Hoover Dam and Powerplant Daily Lake/Reservoir Storage-af Time Series Data',
          'itemId': 6124,
          'order': 'ASC',
          'type': 'csv'}

r = requests.get(url, params)
print(r)
with open('download.csv', 'w', encoding='utf8') as f:
    f.write(r.text)
```

Output:

```
<Response [200]>
```

Comment: Thank you. How would specify where the file downloads to?

Comment: @ShaneS `r.text` contains the data.  Write it to where you want.  I added an example that would put it in the current directory.

Answer (score 1):

Very similar to the excellent answer provided by @MarkTolonen but with an added check for the HTTP status and uses streaming which is potentially more efficient for large amounts of data.

```
import requests
from datetime import date

params = {}
params['after'] = '2020-05-28'
params['before'] = date.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
params['filename'] = 'Lake Mead Hoover Dam and Powerplant Daily Lake/Reservoir Storage-af Time Series Data'
params['order'] = 'ASC'
params['type'] = 'csv'
params['itemId'] = 6124
url = "https://data.usbr.gov/rise/api/result/download"

(r := requests.get(url, params=params, stream=True)).raise_for_status()

with open('data.csv', 'wb') as csv:
    for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=4096):
        csv.write(chunk)
```